# How is the return value of Flask-Security's context processor used?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am trying to customize my register view for flask-security as specified in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html).

```
@security.register_context_processor
def security_register_processor():
    return dict(hello="world")
```

I don't know what `return dict(hello="world")` does. Am I supposed to be able to access this dict in the register_user view? Adding that line of code doesn't do anything to change the template at all.  Is it supposed to show up in the template?  How do I use this feature?

```
   <h1>Register</h1>
   <form action="{{ url_for_security('register') }}" method="POST" name="register_form">
    {{ register_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ register_user_form.email.label }} {{ register_user_form.email }}<br/>
    {{ register_user_form.password.label }} {{ register_user_form.password }}<br/>
    {{ register_user_form.password_confirm.label }} {{ register_user_form.password_confirm }}<br/>
    {{ register_user_form.submit }}
  </form>
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context processor behaves like other Flask context processors.  Each registered function returns a dict of new variables to add to the template context.  From those same docs:

> To add more values to the template context, you can specify a context processor for all views or a specific view.

Your example will add the name `hello`, with the value `'world'` to the context of the register view.  Use it like any other template variable.

```html
Hello, {{ hello }}!
```